# Database Design : Creating database  and User Interface for recurring events

Tags: algorithm, database-design, usability

We are creating web-application of a bus service where people search and book the seat. We want to give a UI to admin where s/he can specify recurring trips.

For example Volvo Bus will run from City1 to City2 every day 9:00 AM except Tuesday. There can be any number of such criteria.

How should I store such different recurring trips which can be searched without perfomance hit? How should it be representd in UI which is easy for admin to work with.

Current Database Design:

```
Table : TRIP_MASTER
TRIP_ID
NAME

Table : TIMETABLE
ID
TRIP_ID
CITY_ID
ARRIVAL_TIME
DEPARTURE_TIME
SEQ_NO
```

Comment: I suppose "every day 9:00 AM accept Tuesday" => "every day 9:00 AM *except* Tuesday" ?

Comment: Suppose one of my recurring trips from City1 to City2 occurs on a Tuesday--a day when, say, there's currently *no* bus scheduled to run between those two cities. Should I be allowed to specify that kind of recurring trip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are a) to store entities representing each occurrence of the recurring trip (as you might populate a calendar table with a row representing each day of the year), an approach that leverages SQL or b) store a rule representing the recurring schedule, which will require more procedural code throughout the application.  I favor option a), even though it requires routines to populate the trip-occurrences table on a periodic basis.

Comment: I would go with option a). I think we need to provide UI like Google calendar recurring event dialog and store all rules somewhere in database against the trip. When user save the rule, create schedules accordingly in TIMETABLE. If user changes the rule, first delete all records from TIMETABLE and create again based on the latest rule.

Comment: The UI is not relevant to the database structure. The database structure is relevant to the UI.  You have to give the user the ability to create/define a route (i.e. the many places the bus stops, and the time of day for each stop) but how you represent the route in the database is something the UI does not need to know about.

Comment: New comment because 5 minutes elapsed and I cannot edit the other one. I am suggesting that for a given period of time, e.g. a year, you create a record for every stop in the route, for evvery day the bus stops at the location, and for every time within the day, if, for example, the bus stops there hourly. Imagine an archeologist studying that route-stop-time table, and then deducing this rule from the raw data: Aha! this route never ran on Tuesdays. You can instantiate the route definition from the location-time rows that comprise it, and sequence of the route's stops is implicit in the time.

Comment: select route, stoplocation, stopdatetime from routes where route = ? and stopdatetime = {some date} order by stopdatetime

Comment: Thanks Tim for you prompt response